# Merge/Concat Columns with same ID without using 'For XML Path

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains data as follows:

```
Name | UserType | Locations
-----------------------
Mike | A        | China
Mike | A        | Australia
Mike | B        | Mexico
Mike | B        | Russia
John | A        | Japan
John | A        | China
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
Name | UserType | Locations
-----------------------
Mike | A        | China, Australia
Mike | B        | Mexico, Russia
John | A        | Japan, China
```

Currently I am able to achieve this by using 'FOR XML PATH' like so:

```
SELECT Name, UserType, Location = 
      STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + location
           from @MyTable b
           where b.name = a.name
           and b.UserType = a.UserType
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM @MyTable a
```

@MyTable being the table in which I am retrieving my data from.

The reason I cannot use this query is because I am dealing with a minimum of about 500,000 records and it takes way to long to complete (I had to select top 100 rows to even check if it was working as I thought my system had hung).

I have been searching around and all I can find for sqlserver is this xml path stuff. **Is it possible to achieve what I want in sql without using xml?** Or should I just get all the records and do it in code? For anyone wondering the output of this is going into an excel generated report which a client then downloads.

Comment: any chance of sql fiddle so we can try out

Comment: The query you show here does not produce your desired output. Since you are querying @MyTable without a filter/group by or distinct it will return 6 rows and haave done the concatenation once for each row. There are other alternatives to concatenating strings in SQL Server than using XML but nothing faster. That might change in the [future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql). I know you don't ask for help with your actual query but to me it looks like that is what you need. There are multiple ways of doing the `for xml` trick wrong .

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Yeah, the code I posted does have some slight errors, as it turns out I was doing it slightly wrong. In anycase though, i made the corrections listed below by Gordon and the query still took over 30 minutes to complete. I have currently managed to get a udf working in sql that completes in about 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

First, write the query like this:

```
SELECT Name, UserType, 
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + location
              FROM @MyTable b
              WHERE b.name = a.name AND b.UserType = a.UserType
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as locations
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name, UserType FROM @MyTable) a;
```

This reduces the work-load to only one subquery call per `Name`/`UserTYpe` pair.

Next, you can an index on `@MyTable(name, UserType, location)`.  You can do this by declaring the combination to be a unique or primary key.  Alternatively, you can use a temporary table and explicitly add the index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, iv made these changes and as of this moment, its been 3 minutes and the query is still executing...

Comment: 10 minutes in and its still going... the issue isnt that it wont complete its that it takes so long to complete. I need this to be fast as a client is then downloading the report and I cannot have them waiting over 10 minutes for it. Is this only possible in code OR via xml?

Comment: @Rhexis . . . Were you able to create the index on all three columns?

Comment: Once the query completes I can try that although I fail to understand how that will help. Is there a way to do this in sql without xml though?

Comment: I dont understand how a select * from @mytable can take 1 second and this xml query can take over 30 mins. Why when I asked for a way without xml are you suggesting still to use xml?

Comment: @Rhexis . . . Because your query just needs an appropriate index.

Comment: Indexing it made no difference. Is this possible without the use of xml?

Comment: @Rhexis . . . Did you use a temporary table?  Temporary tables and table variables might optimize differently.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in probing as to "why query is slow" unless you don't provide your real table structure and sample data.

i) if possible you hv to change your db design.

ii) Why you will wwant to query 5 00,000 records at a time,that too 
using distinct ?

try this,

```
declare @t table(Name varchar(50), UserType varchar(50), Locations varchar(50))
insert into @t VALUES
-----------------------
('Mike','A','China'    )
,('Mike','A','Australia')
,('Mike','B','Mexico'   )
,('Mike','B','Russia'   )
,('John','A','Japan'    )
,('John','A','China'    )

;with CTE as
(
 select * 
 ,ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION by name,usertype order by name)rn
 from @t

)

select name ,usertype
,stuff((select ','+ Locations from cte c1 where c1.name=c.name 
and c.usertype=c1.usertype  for xml path('')),1,1,'')
Locations
from cte c
where rn=1
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding the question, im not asking why its slow, its well known that xml is slow. I am asking for an alternative way to achieve this, one that does not use xml. If there isnt another way to do this then I will just do it in code.

Comment: Also, this is an existing system, I cannot just change the database design its too large to do such a thing. Why 500k+? Because thats the data that I am needing to request from the database, i need it all for a report, it will also be customised for various other data queries that are needed on demand.

Comment: @Rhexis , isn't my query faster than using distinct,just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query :

```
  DECLARE @MyTable TABLE ( Name VARCHAR(100), UserType VARCHAR(100), 
      Locations VARCHAR(100) )

  INSERT INTO @MyTable ( Name , UserType , Locations  ) 
  SELECT 'Mike','A','China' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike','A','Australia' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike','B','Mexico' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike','B','Russia' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John','A','Japan' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John','A','China' 

  SELECT Name , UserType , 
        STUFF (( SELECT  ',' + Locations FROM @MyTable I WHERE I.Name = 
                 O.Name AND I.UserType = O.UserType FOR XML PATH('')) 
              ,1,1,'')
  FROM @MyTable O
  GROUP BY Name , UserType
```

Without XML use below query :

```
  ;WITH CTE ( UniqId , _Id , _Name , _UserType , _Locations) AS
   (
      SELECT 1 , Id , Name , UserType , Locations 
      FROM @MyTable
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT UniqId + 1 , _Id + 1 , _Name , _UserType , _Locations + ',' + 
             Locations
      FROM CTE
      JOIN @MyTable ON _Name = Name AND _UserType = UserType AND _Id < Id 
    )


    SELECT CTE._Name Name, CTE._UserType UserType, CTE._Locations Locations
    FROM CTE
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(UniqId) _UniqId ,_Name , _UserType 
        FROM CTE
        GROUP BY _Name , _UserType
    ) A ON _UniqId = UniqId AND A._Name  = CTE._Name AND A._UserType = 
        CTE._UserType
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this through without using 'For XML Path' with the help of CLR Aggregate function
Try this link [clickHere](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2022/concat-aggregates-sql-server-clr-function/)